# Issue while replacing common-collections-3.2.1.jar with common-collections4-4.3.jar in classpath

Tags: java, maven

Due to Java security vulnerability, it was recommended to replace common-collections-3.2.1.jar with version 3.2.2 and then subsequently with common-collections4-4.3.jar,but doing so caused below error in the code:
Exception occurred on verifyCustomer rule: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/ListOrderedMap.
Checked source files for both common-collections-3.2.2.jar and common.collections4.4.3.jar.
ListOrderedMap class is present in both the files.

Tried below options to resolve the issue:

1. Do maven-tree and find dependencies. - Tried but could not find dependencies as the project is not proper maven project.
2. Check compatibility with different libraries : common-collections4.4.3.jar is compatible with commons-lang.3.8.jar. we tried with both 3.8 as well as 3.12. The issues still persists.

As per a quick search on the internet, it was suggested to go back to previous version, which is not possible in the project, due to security reasons.
Could someone please guide what is missing? Do we need any specific changes (as this is a major version upgrade), apart from adding the jar to the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

The package names have changes between commons-collections and commons-collections4. If you can change the code, you'll need to modify your imports from:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.*
```

to

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.*
```

If you have a transitive dependency relying on commons-collections, then the stacktrace of your NoClassDefFoundError should give you a hint at which class is using ListOrderedMap.